# Office 2013 Click to Run Installer and ActiveX issue

Tags: .net, activex, ms-office

I would like to ask you for support in case described below:

I have created ActiveX control which is the part of web application and is used on WWW.
DSOFrame is supporting this application in order to unload Office control and to open a Word, Excel or Powerpoint file.
It is not problematic if we use computer with Office 2003-2010. Issue is encountered when we used "Click to Run" installer to set up Office 2013 Home and Business.

If I try to open Word or Excel file my application throws exception "The associated COM server does not support ActiveX Document embedding." which in final does not show document. Similar issue I have experienced with "Clck to run" installer for Office 2010. However it was resolved thanks to downloading of the same version with MSI installer and with final reinstallation.

As far I know MSI installer does not exist for Office 2013 Home and Business. In order to download it I used link below http://www.solutions-outlook.com/2013/06/how-to-get-full-installation-of.html .

I downloaded 2 GB IMG disk image. I noticed that it contains "Click to Run" installer instead of MSI package.

I used guideline from https://superuser.com/a/626937 in order to sort out problem with document show. Unfortunately when I decided to deinstall Office 2013 Professional and keep Office 2013 Home and Business my problem was not solved.

I assume that MSI installer for Office 2013 Home and Business and customised installation could resolve my problem.

It works for Office 2010 and Office 2013 Professional. Unfortunately I cannot find mentioned version. Probably Click to Run installer does not install all necessary components for my application.

Have you got any idea or guidliness to solve my problem? Have you ever straggled with something similar? Is any different possibility to load Word or Excel control (excluding DSOFrame) which is compatible with Home and Business version?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DocObject]
```

It is missed in 32-bit registry on 64-bit systems, and dsoframer control fails while checking it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and I fix it by adding this key in the registry: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\DocObject]`, with a string default value set to "16".

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, and I fix it by adding this key in the registry:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}]
Create a key 'DocObject'
Set the default value '16'

This is working with Office 2013 Only

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It took me a while to interpret what the others were saying. I was mistaking the 'key' for a 'string value'. For clarity, here is the code to use. Just put the code below in notepad and save it with a .reg extension (like DocObject.reg) and then double-click it. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\DocObject]
@="16"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{F4754C9B-64F5-4B40-8AF4-679732AC0607}\DocObject]
@="16"
```